# Wordpress site (with http_// and without www) redirects to login

Tags: wordpress, ssl, redirect, admin

I've Googled, searched the Wordpress site, the Stackoverflow site and tried many suggested solutions but my example.com (eg. http://example.com) website keeps redirecting to the Wordpress admin.

I have the standard .htaccess file and WP is installed in a www directory on the server (as per clients request).

**Here's the URL combinations and redirects:**

- example.com =>
  https://www.example.com/wp-login.php?redirect_to=https://www.example.com/wp-admin/
- http://example.com => https://www.example.com/wp-login.php?redirect_to=https://www.example.com/wp-admin/
- https://example.com => https://www.example.com
- www.example.com => https://www.example.com

Somewhere there's a 301 redirect but I cannot figure out where or how.

**What I've tried:**

- Changed Site and Home URLs in admin
- Wordpress Health Check plugin
- Deactivating Redirection plugin
- Installing SSL pluging
- Added to .htaccess:

  ```
  RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
  RewriteRule ^(.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1 [R,L]
  ```

Hopefully someone can help me figure this out.

I used Duplicator plugin to move the site from staging to the live environment.

Answer (score 2):

If you haven't already, deactivate all plugins and switch to a core supplied theme and see what happens after that.

If it works as you expect, then obviously it's an issue in one of you plugins or within the theme you are using.

Reactivate each one my one and retest.

Another thing to try would be adding the following to the .htaccess file and see what that gets you.

```
# NON-WWW -> WWW REDIRECT
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [L,R=301,NC]

# HTTP -> HTTPS REDIRECT
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

i would suggest to check what URL are you using in database (wp_options table), open your phpMyAdmin and look for **siteurl** and **home**. If those URLs don't match with the structure you want to achieve then you can run this query:

```
UPDATE wp_options SET option_value = replace(option_value, 'http://oldExampleURL.com', 'http://newExampleURL.com') WHERE option_name = 'home' OR option_name = 'siteurl';
```

Also one important note, browsers are caching 301 redirects, so it can simply be that.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks. I have not been able fully solve or pinpoint the issue but do think it is cache related.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem by going in WordPress to:
settings -> permalink 
and change it to any option, and then save it.

after that change the permalink to whatever you want, and save it again.

this thing solved the url redirect by recreating them and delete the old missed up  ones.